# mapbox strip-frameworks.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: xcode, mapbox

i am trying to integrate mapBox sdk with xcode, 
i followed the steps metioned here:

[https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/#manual][1]

and i got the following error

```
bash: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MapApp-fyrihrjtsamtymbsepguswqhltvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MapApp.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/strip-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Manual Installation](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/#manual) docs, there is a step to follow for configuring Xcode.  Be certain you followed these steps

- Drag `Mapbox.framework` into your project’s Embedded Binaries section in the project editor
- click the + button at the top and select “New Run Script Phase”

Here are some other discussions that may be useful, but in general the Manual steps from your original link should work.

- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/4729
- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/ios/INSTALL.md#dynamic-framework

I just followed the manual steps for the current version of the Mapbox iOS SDK, and this is what the downloaded folder looks like (some items snipped).  So the file should be there, it is likely a Xcode configuration problem.

[image]

Comment: thank you!  this link helped me: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/4729 , i added a new run script and removed the old one, and it worked

Answer (score 17):

I solved this problem by making sure the Mapbox framework was embedded before the script was run.

Your Build Phases tab should show Embed Frameworks first, like this:
[image: Correct Build Phases ordering]

Comment: I've been struggling with this stupid issue for days. Made my day. You rock!

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer. The reason that removing and re-adding the Run Script step works is that it's going to put the Run Script step last.

Comment: Yes Embeded Frameworks should be before Run Script in Build Phases. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This actually fixed it for me. Drag Embedded Frameworks section above the script phase and it works.